Create a triangle by knowing the feet of the angle bisectors
I searched online for a triangle whose vertices are the feet of the angle bisectors of the triangle on the opposite sides.
But I couldn't find anything useful
The reason behind this is that I saw this triangle at cut the knot site here Where I found a talk about these points in the introductions, but I did not find any mention of these points in the table
I wonder if it is possible to build the original triangle $ΔABC$ using a ruler and a caliper if we know the points $L_a,L_b,L_c$

Also, I searched the Mathworld website to find some information about this triangle here, but it doesn't seem to be on the list.

"mediastina" is not an English word. Are you talking about angle bisectors?

Thanks for the headup, here I modified the question, I am writing using the automatic translation keyboard so I did not pay attention @GerryMyerson

https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jgg/jgg12/j12h2yiu.pdf may be helpful. Also, https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1000

http://www.iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/emath18.pdf says it can't generally be done with straightedge and compass.

Thank you @GerryMyerson This answers my question.

I encourage you to post an answer, based on what you have learned from the link(s) I posted.
